# MySQL change email domains

Tags: mysql, sql, email

I am using benkeens open source script (http://benkeen.github.io/generatedata/) to generate random data. The problem is it gives weird email domains within the database. The code I was using to change the domains is:

```
UPDATE   emails
 SET      email_address = CONCAT(LEFT(email_address, INSTR(column, '@')), 'google.com')
 WHERE    email LIKE '%@magnamalesuada.org%';
```

The only issue is, there are literally a hundred different domains being generated. Is it possible to change domain names to google, yahoo, hotmail, etc in a more efficient way?

Comment: How do you know what the new domain is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an id column, you could use the `%` operator to divide your rows in groups, for example in 3:

```
UPDATE   emails
 SET      email_address = CONCAT(LEFT(email_address, INSTR(column, '@')), 'google.com')
 WHERE    id%3=0;

UPDATE   emails
 SET      email_address = CONCAT(LEFT(email_address, INSTR(column, '@')), 'yahoo.com')
 WHERE    id%3=1;

UPDATE   emails
 SET      email_address = CONCAT(LEFT(email_address, INSTR(column, '@')), 'hotmail.com')
 WHERE    id%3=2;
```